# Use async/await to combine concurrent and sequential requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

Using `async`/`await`, I'm trying to perform three requests as quickly as possible.

`getIndependentThingOne` and `getIndependentThingTwo` return data without submitting any parameters to their endpoints. `getDependentThing`, however, requires the `id` property of the first element of a list returned by `getIndependentThingTwo`. I have *somewhat* tried to follow in principle, what's outlined in [this pizza post](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/even-with-async-await-you-probably-still-need-promises-9b259854c161). At least in spirit.

```
const getIndependentThingOne = async () => {
  const url = `${root}/1`
  return axios.get(url)
}

const getIndependentThingTwo = async () => {
  const url = `${root}/2`
  return axios.get(url)
}

const getDependentThing = async ([{ id }]) => {
  const url = `${root}/3/${id}`
  return axios.get(url)
}

const getIndependentThingOneAndDependentThing = async () => {
  const { data: listFromIndependentThingTwo } = await getIndependentThingTwo()
  const { data: listFromDependentThing } = await getDependentThing(
    listFromIndependentThingTwo
  )
  return {
    listFromIndependentThingTwo,
    listFromDependentThing
  }
}

const getAllData = async () => {
  const [
    { data: listFromIndependentThingOne },
    { listFromIndependentThingTwo, listFromDependentThing }
  ] = await Promise.all([
    getIndependentThingOne(),
    getIndependentThingOneAndDependentThing()
  ])
  console.log('DONE')
  console.log({ listFromIndependentThingOne })
  console.log({ listFromIndependentThingTwo })
  console.log({ listFromDependentThing })
}

getAllData()
```

While this works, I wonder if it is the most optimal way to structure these requests. Returning an object of the last two values and destructuring them here seems a little off somehow

```
const [
  { data: listFromIndependentThingOne },
  { listFromIndependentThingTwo, listFromDependentThing }
]
```

#### Is there a more idiomatic pattern for doing this sort of operation using `async`/`await`?

Comment: no await? not async. A function that does not have the await keyword in it does not need to be marked async, AT ALL.

Comment: @mpm Can you be more specific?

Comment: @1252748 It's pretty explicit, your first 3 functions don't need to be marked async since none of them use the keyword await inside their body. They just return promises.

Comment: ... but marking them as async does not add any overhead, however it makes further readers aware that they are `async` so I think norhigs wrong with that

Comment: @mpm yeah, you're absolutely correct, axios returns a promise anyway. Those are left in there I think from back when I was toying around with some other stuff. Thanks for that catch.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't write that extra `getIndependentThingOneAndDependentThing` function, especially not with `async`/`await`. I'd rather go for plain `then` syntax where it is simpler, and do everything inside `getAllData`:

```
const getIndependentThingOne = () => axios.get(`${root}/1`);
const getIndependentThingTwo = () => axios.get(`${root}/2`);
const getDependentThing = ([{id}]) => axios.get(`${root}/3/${id}`);

const getData = ({data}) => data;

async function getAllData() {
  const promiseOne = getIndependentThingOne().then(getData);
  const promiseTwo = getIndependentThingTwo().then(getData);
  const promiseThree = promiseTwo.then(getDependentThing).then(getData);
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  const [listFromThingOne, listFromThingTwo, listFromThingThree] = await Promise.all([
    promiseOne,
    promiseTwo,
    promiseThree,
  ]);
  console.log('DONE')
  console.log({ listFromThingOne })
  console.log({ listFromThingTwo })
  console.log({ listFromThingThree })
}

getAllData()
```

(Whether `.then(getData)` should be moved inside the `getThing` functions, like `async () => (await axios.get(…)).data`, comes down to preference)

Answer (score 1):

Basic example of **`aysnc/await`**:

```js
console.log('person1: shoe ticket');
console.log('person2: shoe ticket');

const preMovie = async () => {
 const promiseGirlFriendBringingTickets = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve('ticket');
  }, 3000);
 });

 const addButter  = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('butter');
 });

 const getPopcorn  = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('popcorn');
 });

 let ticket = await promiseGirlFriendBringingTickets;

 console.log(`girlfriend: i have the ${ticket}`);
 console.log('boyfriend: we should go in');
 console.log('girlfriend: no i am hungry');

 let popcorn = await getPopcorn;

 console.log(`boyfriend: I got some ${popcorn}`);
 console.log('boyfriend: we should go in');
 console.log('girlfriend: I need butter on my popcorn');

 let butter = await addButter;

 console.log(`boyfriend: I got some ${butter} on popcorn`);
 console.log('boyfriend: anything else baby ?');
 console.log('girlfriend: Lets go we are getting late');

 return ticket;
}
preMovie().then((m) => console.log(`person3: shoes ${m}`));

console.log('person4: shoe ticket');
console.log('person5: shoe ticket');
```

Answer (score 0):

The "dependendThing" could just take a promise of the thing it deends on:

```
const getDependentThing = async (dependentThingTwo) => {
  const { data: listFromIndependentThingTwo } = await dependentThingTwo;
 return getDependentThing(
  listFromIndependentThingTwo
 );
}
```

That way, you can get the results as:

```
const dependentThing = independentThingTwo();
const [listFromTwo, dependentThing] = await Promise.all([dependentThing, getDependendThing(dependentThing)]);
```

Comment: I’m a little confused by the last snippet. Is there a typo there? Also, `const dependedThing = independentThingTwo` seems a little counterintuitive, is that correct?

Comment: Actually, would you mind terribly adding some comments explaining each step? I’m afraid I’m not totally following. Cheers.

Comment: @1252748 yeah its maybe a bit confusing, basically doing the same as bergi

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern is:

```
async function getStuff() {
  // Kick off thing one request, don't wait!
  const thingOnePromise = getIndependentThingOne();

  // Kick off things two request, don't wait quite yet.
  const [{id}] await getIndependentThingTwo();

  await dependentThingThree(id);
  await thingOnePromise;
}
```

In other words, you kick off the first request, without awaiting it. You await it later, when you have to, before the function completes.